# Use specific VM only for TFS Builds

Tags: c#, azure, tfs, build, azure-devops

I am currently building a C# Web API and publishing it to Azure.  I'm using Visual Studio Online to host my TFS source control.  Of course, Azure has options to use their build servers, but those are not free after your first 60 minutes of build time, and this is an educational endeavor.

Is it possible to set up a VM (or use my local machine) as the TFS build server for continuous integration?  How would I go about that?  My initial guess is that this is possible, and I just am not googling using the correct terminology to find what I'm looking for.

I'm not terribly savvy on TFS in depth, so please feel free to correct any incorrect assumptions I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download and install TFS on your local server/machine: [VS & TFS Download page](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs)

But if you need only build server you can use any other CI server as well (e.g. [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) or [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/)) and build your code from visualstudio.com there.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Windows Server VM in Azure, and simply install TFS 2013 and when you get to the configuration wizard just choose to configure Build Server only.  When it asks you for the URL to your collection, give it the URL for your VSO collection (e.g. https://foo.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection)

Pretty straightforward to do, I've done it many times.

PS - Of course you could use an on-premise VM also, but I like the option of using a VM in Azure.

Comment: Right, but that's not a free service, right?  VM's are charged by the minute to my understanding.  Of course I agree - this would be a much easier option.

Comment: You don't get anything for free. Your on premises server takes up space and resources that cost. Azure costs are below real local costs.